# The namespace already contains a definition in wsdl-generated file

Tags: c#, reporting-services, wsdl

I'm trying to integrate reporting services in an C# application, but when I'm trying to compile it I'm getting a bunch of 'already contains' errors, just like those two:

```
error CS0101: The namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005' already contains a definition for 'ListSecureMethodsCompletedEventHandler'
error CS0101: The namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005' already contains a definition for 'GetRenderResourceCompletedEventHandler'
```

They all come from ReportingServices2005.cs file, which was generated using wsdl and which I included in the project. What am I doing wrong here?

I probably should also mention that I'm using ReportingService2010.cs and ReportExecution.cs.

Comment: If you don't use ReportingServices2005 endpoint, you can exclude the file from the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was easy enough. It was my first time using ReportingServices in C# and I misread the documentation. I thought both ReportingService2005 and 2010 are needed. After excluding ReportingService2005 and changing a few things everything worked.